# Why am I unable to access .map variable outside of the Return function?

Tags: reactjs, variables

I have this card which displays a bunch of dummy shop items which I render in the return area. However, the onClick function AddToCart will not let me access the data.price variable from the shopData.map function. It only works if I declare the setTotal function directly in the onClick function in the return area. Do you know how I can access the shopData.price in the function addToCart() ?

```
export  function Cart() {
  
  const {total, setTotal} = useContext(testContext)


  function  addToCart(){
    ()=> setTotal(total+data.price)
  }


  return (
    <>
      
    <div class='grid-container card-img-top'>
      
      {shopData.map((data, index) => (
      <div class='grid-item-1'>
      <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} key={data.index}>
      <Card.Img variant="top" src={data.imageUrl} />
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Text class='card-title'>
          {data.name}
        </Card.Text>
        <Card.Text class='card-price'>
        {data.price}
        </Card.Text>
        <button class='add-cart-btn' onClick={addToCart}>Add to Cart </button>
      </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      </div>
         ))}
      
      </div>
    </>
        
  )
}
```

Within the return area, tried this which works, but now when i want to add multiple functions onClick I can't.

onClick={()=> setTotal(total+data.price)}

Answer (score 0):

```
export  function Cart() {
  
  const {total, setTotal} = useContext(testContext)


  function addToCart(price){
     setTotal(total+price)
  }


  return (
    <>
      
    <div class='grid-container card-img-top'>
      
      {shopData.map((data, index) => (
      <div class='grid-item-1'>
      <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} key={data.index}>
      <Card.Img variant="top" src={data.imageUrl} />
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Text class='card-title'>
          {data.name}
        </Card.Text>
        <Card.Text class='card-price'>
        {data.price}
        </Card.Text>
        <button class='add-cart-btn' onClick={()=>addToCart(data?.price)}>Add to Cart </button>
      </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      </div>
         ))}
      
      </div>
    </>
        
  )
}
```

Here in this case when you click on `Add To Cart` button. It will call `addToCart(price)` function and pass it price of that perticular item to your function as argument.

now inside function you can access the price in parameter and set it into your `setTotal`.